# python operators for numpy.ndarray like class

Tags: python, numpy

I have a class that has a numpy.ndarray as a member and behaves similar to ndarray by overloading `__getitem__` and `__getattr__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(values):
        # numpy.ndarray
        self._values = values

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._values[key]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._values, name)
```

Thus I can use the numpy method like shape, size, ... directly on an object of this class. I can also do things like `obj.__add__(1)`, which will add 1 to `obj._values`. However, if I try `obj + 1` it raises "unsupported operand type(s)". I would like to get the same behaviour for `obj + 1` as `obj.__add__(1)`. Is this possible without adding `__add__` to `Foo`?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You must implement `__add__`.

Comment: Numpy 1.13rc2 has a mixin class that implements all these methods for you (`numpy.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do here, but it's not going to work the way you think it should. This is a very non-obvious subtlety in Python.

What you're thinking is that what you do `obj + 1` Python is actually calling `obj.__add__(1)` and that, failing to find an `__add__` attribute on `obj` it will fall through to its `__getattr__`.

But this is not exactly how it works for arithmetic operators, the implementation of which is actually significantly more complicated. In this case if `obj` does not have an `__add__` method, it will attempt to call the right-hand operand's `__radd__` (for "right add") method to see if `1` knows how to add with the left-hand operator. It does not so you get an exception.

There are other subtleties involving type slots that I won't get into.

If you want your class to act as a proxy for an `ndarray` you have a few options. It really depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish, which you might consider asking in a separate question. You might just be able to *subclass* `ndarray` directly and implement your additional functionality in the subclass.

If you don't want a subclass of `ndarray` you might also consider using a proxy, such as the `ObjectProxy` from [wrapt](http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html). This may or may not be what you want. It will make an object that walks, talks, quacks like, and is even named `ndarray`, though you can still subclass `ObjectProxy` to override methods that you don't want proxied.

Otherwise there's the tedious manual method.

Comment: Thanks! I don't really want to subclass ndarray, as it is non-trivial and also I'm quite happy with the fact that I cannot do `obj[i,j] = 2` if I don't define `__setitem__`. I will look into proxying or add everything manually.

Comment: FWIW *in general* subclassing `ndarray` is not hard, but not knowing more about your use case I couldn't say.